# No module named open3d

Tags: python

I am trying to compile a python program (by running "python file.py"), but it gives me the error of "No module named open3d". I have installed open3d on my Mac system using "pip3 install open3d-python". I am also running python 3.10.4 64 bit.

I reinstalled python 3.10 and that comes with pip, so I am pretty sure that when I use pip to install packages they go in the same place. My vscode also doesn't show any errors when I am interpreting using 3.10, unlike 3.9 where there are yellow squiggles below my import line.

I have looked at other posts about a module not found but their fixes don't seem to work for me.

Comment: What is the command you are using that gives you this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

open3d library is currently not available for python version 3.10. I am solve it by installing with python 3.8.

### The supported environment for open3d:

Supported Python versions:

3.6

3.7

3.8

3.9

Supported operating systems:

Ubuntu 18.04+

macOS 10.15+

Windows 10 (64-bit)

If you have other Python versions or operating systems, please refer to [Build from source](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/compilation.html#compilation) and compile Open3D from source.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you install open3d with `pip3 install open3d-python`?

[The official instruction](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/getting_started.html) gives `pip3 install open3d`.

Did you run your python via `python` in cmd? Maybe trying `python3` could help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried pip3 install open3d but it said it couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement. Only doing open3d-python worked. I tried compiling with "python3 myfile.py" and it said "ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/open3d/macos/open3d.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyThreadState_Current
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/open3d/macos/open3d.so
  Expected in: flat namespace"

Comment: @destroyer806 Can you try `apt install libgl1-mesa-glx`? I'd met a similar error (dlopen error) inside of the docker using `pytorch/pytorch:1.8.0-cuda11.1-cudnn-devel` image, with `pip install open3d` (not open3d-python) and solved it via that command